# How to take specific input from file with class objects and compare it to a value , then output certain lines

Tags: c++, file, class, compare

I created a class with all the variables , in the main program I am supposed to take the input from a dat file, compare the height and weight to an instantiated object and if less then it should be output to another file . I am struggling with the main program and I do not know where I am going wrong. It keeps either giving me an infinite loop either on the exe or on the output file (0).

Here is my header file to give you an idea :

```
class Baby
{
public:
    Baby();
    Baby(string n, string a, char s, double w, double l);
    ~Baby();

    char getSex() const;
    string getName() const;

    friend bool operator < (const Baby& b1, const Baby& b2);


    friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, Baby& m);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outs, const Baby& m);
private:
    string name;
    string address;
    char sex;
    double weight;
    double length;
};
```

Those private variables are in the file . So weight and height must be compared and if less , then all 6 lines must be outputted .

Baby averageBaby(" "," ",' ', 3.2 , 52);     ......The instantiated object

Baby babies;

I then used the loop :

```
while(!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> babies;
        if(babies < averageBaby)
            outfile << babies <<endl;

    }
```

But this gave me an infinte loop on the exe .

I also tried

```
 while(!infile.eof())
    {
        infile >> namee >> addresss >> sexx >> weightt >>lengthh;

        if(baby1 < averageBaby)
            outfile << baby1;
    }
```

This gave me an infinite loop of zeros on the output file .

This is the overloaded comparison operator

```
bool operator < (const Baby& b1, const Baby& b2)
{
    return (b1.weight < b2.weight && b1.length < b2.length);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong or advice. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the file was opened properly and is valid?

Comment: Yes , I checked to make sure and they work fine.